# Универсальный bat скрипт для компиляции ассемблерных программ

Tags: ассемблер, bat, masm32

Хочу написать универсальный скрипт для сборки ассемблерных программ, в котором можно настроить все, что связано с компиляцией, и собирать проекты одним запуском. Нашел что-то вроде такого файла, но он не работает:

```
@set srcs   = main.asm
@set target = main.exe

@set masm_home = C:\masm32
@set masm_lib  = %masm_home%\lib
@set masm_inc  = %masm_home%\include
@set masm_bin  = %masm_home%\bin

@set as = %masm_bin%\ml.exe
@set ld = %masm_bin%\link.exe

@if exist *.obj del *.obj

@set as_flags = /c /coff /nologo /I%masm_inc%

@for %%f in (%srcs%) do (
    %as% %as_flags% %%f
    @if errorlevel 1 exit
)

@if exist *.exe del *.exe

@set ld_files = *.obj
@set ld_flags = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:%target% /LIBPATH:%masm_lib%

%ld% %ld_flags% %ld_files%
```

При запуске ошибок нет, но программа не ассемблируется. Вывод значений переменных при помощи echo тоже не работает. Вместо вывода строк печатается "режим echo включен". Еще я не знаю, что означает знак @ перед инструкциями.

Как правильно написать этот скрипт?

Comment: рекомендую для отладки удалить символ экранирования **@**, везде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что в bat именем переменной считается все символы, начиная от первого непробельного после `set` и заканчивая последним символом перед знаком `=`. Значением переменной считается все символы, начиная от первого символа после `=` и заканчивая концом строки.

Например, объявление

```
@set srcs   = main.asm
```

объявляет переменную с именем `"srcs   "` и значением `"  main.asm"`. Т.к. переменной `"srcs"` не существует, то вызов

```
echo %srcs%
```

приведет к вызову

```
echo
```

А такой вызов отображает текущее значение режима вывода команд (echo).

Вызов

```
echo %srcs   %
```

выведет

```
  main.asm
```

(с начальными пробелами).

Т.е. все переменные вы должны объявлять в стиле

```
@set srcs=main.asm
```

---

> я не знаю, что означает знак @ перед инструкциями.

Символ `@` отключает вывод этой команды в консоль. После команд

```
echo 1
@echo 2
```

вы увидите вывод

```
echo 1
1
2
```

Т.к. перед первым `echo` не стоял символ `@`, то вывелась вначале сама команда, а потом ее результат. Вывод команд на консоль можно отключить глобально командой

```
@echo off
```

Тогда все `@` не нужны